# jquery height/width if statement not working

Tags: jquery, html, css

```
$(window).load(function () {

    var $imgs = $('.boxInner img');

    $imgs.each(function () {
        var w = $(this).clientWidth;
        var h = $(this).clientHeight;

        if (w < h) { $(this).css("display","none"); };
    });
});
```

I've tried to write this in so many different ways to no avail. Basically, just look at the picture width and height. If the height is greater than the width turn the display to none.
Somebody please help me figure this out. Should be so simple.

Comment: It's a bad idea to put your open bracket on a different line due to automatic semicolon insertion in javascript

Comment: You want $(document).ready not $(window).load

Comment: Sorry Tim, that was a copy/paste error when I posted.

Comment: The difference between document.ready and window.load is, that all the images are loaded already and you can get a height and a widht. But this can be a race condition, when using document.ready. Image could be in browser-cache before and everything is fine. But if not you get 0 for the image dimensions.

Comment: @TimVermaelen Note that it's only a bad idea with [restricted productions](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.9.1), such as a `return` statement. Though it can be a good idea to be consistent between those and other statements, it's not required. ASI isn't that eager in most cases.

Answer (score 2):

either use the dom objects and its api:

```
$imgs.each(function () {
    var w = this.clientWidth;
    var h = this.clientHeight;

    if (w < h) { $(this).css("display","none"); };
});
```

or use jQuery objects and its api:

```
$imgs.each(function () {
    var w = $(this).width();
    var h = $(this).height();

    if (w < h) { $(this).css("display","none"); };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// you want $(window).load() because you need to make sure your images are loaded before you can run this function
$(window).load(function (){
    var imgs = $('.boxInner img');

    if (imgs.length){
        $.each(imgs, function (index, item){
            var w = item.width(),
                h = item.height();

            if (w < h) { 
                item.css({display: "none"}); 
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Truth is I was using the display:none as a test to see if anything was happening. But it's doing the job now.

Comment: Not bad but some practice learns you to not query `$(this)` multiple times since you will execute jQuery sizzle selector everytime.

Comment: Another "trick" with `$.each()` is to pass your object as first parameter. That way you have more chance to loop over array-like objects. In your case it doesn't matter really. In practice you can run in to problems. The callback has your jQuery item object as an argument so no need to run `$(this)` multiple times. For the `css()` function your syntax is also correct for one change. Yet I try to avoid the use of strings in javascript.

Comment: Tim, did you edit your code? I feel like I'm taking crazy pills. The block above is not working and the code I was using before did. And I've lost it

Answer (score 1):

As I wrote in the comment, if you use window.load you have to wait for all ressources of the page will load. You can do it better with image.complete in combination with $(image).load(function() ...
Or look for a image loader plugin there are much on the web.