# jquery height/width if statement

Tags: jquery, html, css

Sorry I need to ask this again because I had a working piece of code but I lost it.

Can anyone tell me why this is having no effect?

```
$(window).load(function (){
var imgs = $('.boxInner img');

if (imgs.length){
    $.each(imgs, function (index, item){
        var w = item.width(),
            h = item.height();

        if (w < h) { 
            item.css({display: "none"}); 
        }
    });
}
});
```

Idea is to look at group of images, compare the width and height, if the image is taller than it is wide, it disappears.

Thanks.

Comment: I think my last post had a correct answer, but the user that posts it deleted it. Or something....

Comment: You may just need to refresh the page.  His answer is still on your previous question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery height/width if statement not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19548462/jquery-height-width-if-statement-not-working)

Comment: What I mean to say is that was not necessarily the right answer. I may have been mistaken.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/19548462/1183010

Answer (score 2):

The elements passed to an `each()` callback are raw DOM elements, not jQuery objects.

To call jQuery methods like `height()` or `width()`, you need to create a jQuery object using `$()`.

Your browser's error console will try to tell you this if you look at it when running your code.

Answer (score 1):

try this.. you need to wrap your item reference in a jQuery Element object:

```
$(window).load(function (){
    var imgs = $('.boxInner img');

    if (imgs.length){
         $.each(imgs, function (index, item){
              var w = $(item).width(),
                  h = $(item).height();

              if (w < h) { 
                  $(item).css({display: "none"}); 
              }
         });
    }
});
```

..

**UPDATE:**

what about using the traversing **each()** method:

http://api.jquery.com/each/

```
$(window).load(function (){
    var imgs = $('.boxInner img');

    if(imgs.length !== 0){
        imgs.each(function(index, item){

            var $item = $(item),
                w = $item.width(),
                h = $item.height();

            if (w < h) { 
                $item.hide(); 
            }
        });
    }
```

});

try the above.. it also makes sure the length does not equal zero and also just uses the jQuery hide() method

Comment: No luck :( The image still shows up. But good advice nonetheless. Thanks